# Content not touching the sides of the screen

Tags: html, header, margin, document-body

I want to have my header in a div, but the div isn't directly touching any of the page, but there is a little bit of room on the sides. Why? And how can I remove that?
The div is just

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="images/header.png" width="600" height="252" alt="Header" />
</div>
```

And the style.css file contains

```
.header {
    background: url(../images/header_extend.png) repeat-x center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header img {
   display:block;
   margin:0px auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The header_extend.png is to fill the rest of the screen width.

Comment: can you post a link to a demo?

Comment: No, sorry, I make the site on my computer :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the default margin from the body tag.

```
body { margin:0 }
```

Additionally, if you want to use percentage for the `.header` div's width, you should specify the parent's width as well. In case the parent is the body tag, this is what you can do:

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uAcd/)

Comment: That was the Solution! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

try to add css:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
.div {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

and if it's still not working so trim your code to one line. sometimes there is a little space of 1px that come from the breaking line.

like this:

```
<div class="header"><img src="images/header.png" width="600" height="252" alt="Header" /></div>
```

Comment: Still some space at the top

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a reset to the top of your CSS. It often squashes these little spacing bugs.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/